# How to Set font-color and size in gridview using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview, itext

I'm exporting temporary DataGrid to PDF by using the Following Code,

```
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        CDbAccess db = new CDbAccess();
        IDbConnection conn = db.GetConnectionInterface();
        conn.Open();

        IDbCommand cmd = db.GetCommandInterface(str);

        IDbDataAdapter da = db.GetDataAdapterInterface(cmd);
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            // da.Dispose();
            conn.Dispose();
        }

        GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DeepSkyBlue;

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
            "attachment;filename=BugReport.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();

        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
```

And the Output is looking worse, so that i need to align the Output.

And i just want to set Font color and Font Size to particular column.

How to set it using C#?

Comment: Before you get too far, `HTMLWorker` from iTextSharp is considered obsolete in favor of `XMLWorker`. The former has nearly zero support for CSS and has a more limited HTML parser. I would strongly recommend switching over to `XMLWorker`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns property references the columns in your grid-view setup, if you wanted to just access a targeted column in a specific row then:

```
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ControlStyle.Font.Size = 40;
```

Comment: How to set it For whole Gridview?

Comment: You set it directly in the Gridview E.G

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"  Font-Size="X-Small" 
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" >